# Word count after executing mysql query

Tags: python, count

Below is my Python code. I have no problem executing this code. But the final thing I want to accomplish is a word count of the result of the query that fetches the field, titled `comment`.

The query fetches the field `comment` and strips it from all HTML, tabs and new line breaks. The `print(row)` shows me the correct and desired result.

Now I want to count the words of that result. When I do:
`print(len(row.split()))`
this results in error:
`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'`

Or this:
`print(len(re.findall(r'[ \n]+', row)))`
results in:
`TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object, got 'tuple'`

That last example however, gives me a result of 37 when I hard code it like this (for testing)

```
myString = 'Alexei Navalny, who has died suddenly aged 47 while in prison, was Russia’s best-known campaigner against high-level corruption. For many years he was the leading critic and opponent of President Vladimir Putin and his political party, United Russia.'
print(len(re.findall(r'[ \n]+', myString)))
```

To summarize, I fetch one row and in that row is the field (the column) `comment`. I want a word count of the text in that specific field. How can I accomplish this? It's not important for me if the count is a couple of words off. An estimate count will be OK.

```
import re
import requests
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(
host='myHost',
user=('myUsername'),
passwd=('myPassword'),
database=('myDB')
)

mycursor = db.cursor()

try: 
       mycursor.execute("SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(`comment`, '(<[^>]*>)|(&nbsp;)', ''), '\t', ''), '\n', '') AS Replaced_Comment FROM data WHERE id = 1") 
except: 
        print('Sorry ! There was an error ')  
finally:  
        results = mycursor.fetchall()
        for row in results:
                print(row)
        db.commit()
```

Comment: row is a tuple containing the fetched row.  try `row[0]`

Comment: if that doesn't help, please do show exactly what `print(row)` produced

Comment: I made a screenshot. You can view it here: https://imgur.com/Nl4D7fO the text I get back from `print(row)` is:  ('Alexei Navalny, who has died suddenly aged 47 while in prison, was Russia�s best-known campaigner against high-level corruption. For many years he was the leading critic and opponent of President Vladimir Putin and his political party, United Russia.',)

Comment: I tried your suggestion `ysth` and wrapped it into the statement: `print(len(re.findall(r'[ \n]+', row[0]))) and` that worked and gave a result of 37 which is good enough for me. [link](https://imgur.com/FebB9FB)